# Are graphql codegen types correct

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, strapi

I'm trying to create a simple next app with typescript using Strapi as a headless CMS.

I just want to use Strapi and graphql with typescript to show something in the next app.

In Strapi I simply have a Color Content type with two colors, red and blue

I have graphql set up in Strapi and in the playground this works

```
query ColorData{
  colors{
    data{
      attributes{
        color_name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this outputs

```
{
  "data": {
    "colors": {
      "data": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "color_name": "Red"
          }
        },
        {
          "attributes": {
            "color_name": "Blue"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the next app I'm using graphql codegen to generate the types

```
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: "http://0.0.0.0:1337/graphql",
  documents: "graphql/**/*.ts",
  generates: {
    "./src/__generated__/": {
      preset: "client",
      plugins: []
    }
  }
};

export default config
```

The types it outputs relating to colors are

```
export type Color = {
  __typename?: 'Color';
  color_name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']['output']>;
  createdAt?: Maybe<Scalars['DateTime']['output']>;
  publishedAt?: Maybe<Scalars['DateTime']['output']>;
  updatedAt?: Maybe<Scalars['DateTime']['output']>;
};

export type ColorEntity = {
  __typename?: 'ColorEntity';
  attributes?: Maybe<Color>;
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['ID']['output']>;
};

export type ColorEntityResponse = {
  __typename?: 'ColorEntityResponse';
  data?: Maybe<ColorEntity>;
};

export type ColorEntityResponseCollection = {
  __typename?: 'ColorEntityResponseCollection';
  data: Array<ColorEntity>;
  meta: ResponseCollectionMeta;
};

export type ColorFiltersInput = {
  and?: InputMaybe<Array<InputMaybe<ColorFiltersInput>>>;
  color_name?: InputMaybe<StringFilterInput>;
  createdAt?: InputMaybe<DateTimeFilterInput>;
  id?: InputMaybe<IdFilterInput>;
  not?: InputMaybe<ColorFiltersInput>;
  or?: InputMaybe<Array<InputMaybe<ColorFiltersInput>>>;
  publishedAt?: InputMaybe<DateTimeFilterInput>;
  updatedAt?: InputMaybe<DateTimeFilterInput>;
};

export type ColorInput = {
  color_name?: InputMaybe<Scalars['String']['input']>;
  publishedAt?: InputMaybe<Scalars['DateTime']['input']>;
};
```

but if I try to use this in the next app the type don't seem to work with the data form the query.

```
'use client'
import { COLOR_DATA} from '@/graphql/queries'
import { Color, ColorEntityResponse, ColorEntityResponseCollection } from '@/src/__generated__/graphql'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'

const Home = () => {

  const {data, loading} = useQuery<ColorEntityResponseCollection, ColorEntityResponse>(COLOR_DATA)

  if(loading || !data) return <div>Loading</div>

  console.log(data)

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {data.data.map((color:Color) => {
          <li>{color.color_name}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

If I remove the types

```
<ColorEntityResponseCollection, ColorEntityResponse>
```

the console works but with the types it just shows loading.

Is there something I am doing wrong with the codegen ?

Comment: Could you just link the GitHub repo or whatever for your project? It doesn't have to be your actual project; we just need a [mre]. This problem is too complex for us to just banter back and forth to solve.

Comment: I'll sort that out

Answer (score 0):

The types you provided in the query is incorrect. Codegen generates an output type for each query, and that’s the one you should use. This type contains only the fields specified in the query, and its structure exactly matches the structure of the query. So in your case, the type would look like this:

```
type ColorDataQuery = { 
    colors: { 
        data: [{
            attributes: { 
                color_name: string 
            } 
        }] 
    }
};
```

As you can see, the structure of this type is more deeply nested than `ColorEntityResponseCollection`. Additionally, in this type structure, there is no field such as `ColorEntity.id`, unlike `ColorEntityResponseCollection`.

You don’t need to explicitly specify this type. `useQuery` automatically determines it based on the provided query body. However, this automation involves the following steps:

1. Declare the query body.
   The declaration may vary depending on the codegen config, but in your case, the query body should look like this:

```
import { graphql } from '@/src/__generated__';

const COLOR_DATA = graphql(`
    query ColorData{
      colors{
        data{
          attributes{
            color_name
          }
        }
      }
    }
`);
```

2. Run the codegen command: `npx graphql-codegen`
3. Implement the query call through `useQuery`:

```
import { COLOR_DATA} from '@/graphql/queries';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const Home = () => {
  const {data, loading} = useQuery(COLOR_DATA);
  ...
};
```

After these steps, you will see how the IDE highlights the type that the query’s output will have.
[image: the IDE highlighting]

Most likely, the IDE will also highlight that the fields you are trying to access have different location. The correct field access looks like this:

```
const Home = () => {
    const {data, loading} = useQuery(COLOR_DATA);

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {data.colors.data.map((color) =>
                    (<li>{color.attributes.color_name}</li>)
                )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

The related article: [TypeScript with Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/)

Comment: if I do this `<li>{color.attributes.color_name}</li>` its says `Property 'attributes' does not exist on type 'Color'.`

Comment: Have you removed the explicit type of the `map` argument? `.map((color: Сolor) => ...)` => `.map((color) => ...)`

Comment: I have but then I get `Parameter 'color' implicitly has an 'any' type.`, I thought the reason for using typescript was to have a type for everything

Comment: Hmmm... This means that something is wrong. Parameter `color` should implicitly have concrete type (cropped version of `ColorEntity`). I suppose your `data` from the `useQuery` call also has `any` type. Can you check it? The type should be `ColorDataQuery | undefined`

Comment: What am I checking, what type should be `ColorDataQuery | undefined`

Comment: `const {data, loading} = useQuery(COLOR_DATA);` I suppose in this line both `data` and `COLOR_DATA` implicitly have `any` type in your code. It can happen only if Codegen didn't generate the type for the query. This type should be placed to `__generated__/graphql.ts` file when generation is successfully complete.

Comment: I think Codegen can't find the file with the query body because the path to this file doesn't match this rule: `graphql/**/*.ts`. Maybe it's `*.tsx`, not `*.ts` or something like that. Try to play with this rule using the algo: 1. Change the rule; 2. Run command `npx graphql-codegen`; 3. Check the type of `COLOR_DATA`. When the type stops being `any`, you win. I have no other ideas on how to help you right now. I need to see the project structure for more specific help

Comment: You should check 1) if there was any error during the generation 2) if the type of file containing the query is allowed in your codegen config 3) try adding the magic Graphql comment, eg. `gql( /* GraphQL */ )` to see if that helps your IDE and codegen to find the graphql content